# Ordering data by boolean

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a bit of EF Lambda code which returns a list of data from the db table, then orders by a field called `IsDefault`

At first, the code was

```
var listOfData = Db
    .TableName
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .OrderBy(u => u.IsDefault)
    .ToList();
```

Which when writing down, sounds correct. However is wrong as this will order by 0 > 1, and True = 1.

So I changed the statement to;

```
var listOfData = Db
    .TableName
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
    .OrderBy(u => u.IsDefault ? 0 : 1)
    .ToList();
```

However, I could have also written this 2 other ways.

```
.OrderBy(u => !u.IsDefault)
```

OR

```
.OrderByDescending(u => u.IsDefault)
```

Now in my mind, `u.IsDefault ? 0 : 1` reads better, and the other two could be misread as the not wanting the default value first.

What is your view on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use either ordering on the server side because it looks like the ordering only matters for displaying the data. I cannot imagine why it should matter from the programmatic point of view.

Let the client, its view, its display control, or whatever sort the items according to its needs.

Comment: Good point actually. Could just do the ordering when building up the view model.

Comment: I am going with this answer, as it is the simpler solution for my needs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When reading the code the following is most clear and fastest to understand:

```
OrderBy(u => u.IsDefault ? 0 : 1)
```

It sounds like: *"order by: if `default` then 0=top if `not default` then 1=bottom"*

The following is hard to understand:

```
OrderByDescending(u => u.IsDefault)
```

It sounds like: *"Oder descending by IsDefault? WTH? Which goes first `default` or `not default`? `true` or `false`? OK `true`=`1` and `false`=`0` so `false` is first so `not default` is first, but it is descending then `non default` is last so `default` is first. Finally I get it: Default value goes first."*

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `.OrderBy(u => !u.IsDefault)` the other 2 don't quite fit in my opinion.

You have 2 alternative options

1. Declare a property that is called `IsNotDefault` and use it there `.OrderBy(u => u.IsNotDefault)` it will return `!IsDefault` so it flips the results.
2. The best option would be to use `enum` :

   ```
   public enum MyEnum
   {
       Default,
       NonDefault,
   }
   ```

   **Note** think of a better name for that `enum`..

   Now you can use it just like your ternary operator but without the ternary operator :

   ```
   public MyEnum IsDefault {...}
   .OrderBy(u => u.IsDefault)
   ```

   You can even apply more values and it will still order them in the right way.

Comment: Yeah actually considered using Enums, will take a look.

Comment: Why the down-vote ?

Comment: Not me, you still got a +1 from me.

Comment: I'm just wondering  if there is anything incorrect in the answer :P

Comment: As much as this is a great option. For now my needs are purely for boolean, and it would require too much of a code update for introducing the Enum. Thanks for your help.